# sparql - get a list of cities in certain country from dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to get triples about cities, which are from certain country. How can I do that?
I tried:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?c rdfs:label ?name . ?c rdfs:comment ?desc }
WHERE {
  ?c dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_settlement> . 
  ?c rdfs:label ?name .
  ?c rdfs:comment ?desc .
  ?c <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?country . ?country a <http://dbpedia.org/resource/CountryName>
  FILTER ( lang(?name) = "en" && lang(?desc) = "en" )
}
```

but no luck :/ how can i do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CONSTRUCT { ?c rdfs:label ?name }
WHERE {
  ?c dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_settlement> . 
  ?c rdfs:label ?name .
  ?c dbpedia-owl:country <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> .
  OPTIONAL { ?c dbpedia-owl:areaCode ?areacode }
  FILTER ( lang(?name) = "pl" && ?population > 5000)
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: This query won't work, as the resource `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country>` is not a country. If you meant *Country* to be a placeholder for a real country name, please clarify in your answer. Also, `dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_settlement>` implies that `?c rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement`, because that is how the conversion works. Asking for type is more common.